# How to turn compression on/off for .qrc in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

How to turn compression on/off  for .qrc in Visual Studio ?

There is command line option for it.

```
        .rcc -no-compress myresources.qrc
```

but how to achieve this in visual stuio ? Please Help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to add `myresources.qrc` file to your VS project and configure `rcc` command line options as shown on the screenshot below:

[image]

For detailed information on how to configure a custom build tool you can also refer to this [documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hefydhhy%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).